# How to improve this sql query performace?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have two tables `Company` (almost 60K records) and `Position` (almost 600K records)

`Company` table:

```
CompanyID     INT                --PRIMARY KEY
CompanyName   NVARCHAR(100)      
CompanyType   INT               --Just can be (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

`Position` table:

```
PositionID       INT             --Primary key
PositionName     NVARCHAR(100)   
CompanyID        INT             --FK point to Company Table
WorkExperience   INT             --Just can be (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
WorkType         INT             --Just can be (1,2) 
CreateTime       datetime
UpdateTime       datetime
```

I have created a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on the `Company` table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_1] ON [dbo].[Company] 
(
    [CompanyKind] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [CompanyName]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And I have created two `NONCLUSTERED INDICES` ON the `Position` table also:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_6] ON [dbo].[Position] 
(
    [CompanyID] ASC
)ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_8] ON [dbo].[Position] 
(
    [UpdateTime] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My paging stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spIndexJobList]
    @KeyWord NVARCHAR(50) ,
    @WorkExperience INT ,
    @WorkType INT ,
    @CompanyType INT ,
    @PageSize INT ,
    @PageNumber INT 
    --@RowCount INT OUTPUT
AS 
    DECLARE @RowStart INT
    DECLARE @RowEnd INT
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(2000) 

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT C.CompanyID,C.CompanyName,P.PositionName,P.PositionID,P.UpdateTime, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY P.UpdateTime DESC) AS RowNumber FROM Company C INNER JOIN Position P ON C.CompanyID=P.CompanyID WHERE 1=1 '
    IF @KeyWord!=''
      SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND PositionName LIKE @KeyWord'
    IF @WorkExperience !=0 
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND P.WorkExperience=@WorkExperience'
    IF @CompanyType != 0 
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND C.CompanyType=@CompanyType'
    IF @WorkType !=0
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND P.WorkType=@WorkType'
    SET @ParamDefinition = ' @KeyWord    NVarchar(50),
                             @WorkExperience   INT,
                             @WorkType       INT,
                             @CompanyType       INT,
                             @PageSize   INT,
                             @PageNumber INT'
    IF @PageNumber > 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber - 1
            SET @RowStart = @PageSize * @PageNumber + 1 ;
            SET @RowEnd = @RowStart + @PageSize - 1 ;
            SET @SQL = '
        WITH AllJobs
             AS (' + @SQL
                + ')

   SELECT *,(SELECT Count(RowNumber)  FROM   AllJobs) AS TotalRows FROM   AllJobs  WHERE  RowNumber >='
                + STR(@RowStart) + '  AND RowNumber <= ' + STR(@RowEnd) + ''

            EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition,
                @KeyWord, @WorkExperience,@WorkType, 
                @CompanyType, @PageSize, @PageNumber

        END
```

My call statement is this:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spIndexJobList]
        @KeyWord='',
        @WorkExperience = 3,
        @CompanyType = 2,
        @WorkType =1,
        @PageSize = 30,
        @PageNumber =2000

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
(30 row(s) affected)
Table 'Company'. Scan count 3, logical reads 632, physical reads 0
Table 'Position'. Scan count 3, logical reads 4865, physical reads 0
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

[image]

The execute plan prompt missing index on(WorkExperience,WorkType).
But after created index on (WorkExperience,WorkType) query slower.

Anyone give me some suggestions will very appreciate. Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: can you provide more info about the node "Clustered Index Scan" which costs 32%? As well as the "Key Lookup" node which costs 19%.

Comment: A likely performance boost might be not using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DDL:**

***Company table:***

```
CompanyID     INT NOT NULL PK
CompanyName   NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL     
CompanyType   TINYINT NOT NULL
```

***Position table:***

```
PositionID       INT NOT NULL PK
PositionName     NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL   
CompanyID        INT NOT NULL
WorkExperience   TINYINT NOT NULL
WorkType         TINYINT NOT NULL
CreateTime       SMALLDATETIME
UpdateTime       SMALLDATETIME
```

**Index:**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Position
     ON Position (WorkExperience, WorkType, PositionName)
     INCLUDE (UpdateTime)
```

**SP:**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spIndexJobList]

      @KeyWord NVARCHAR(50) 
    , @WorkExperience TINYINT 
    , @WorkType TINYINT 
    , @CompanyType INT 
    , @PageSize INT 
    , @PageNumber INT 

AS BEGIN

     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     IF @PageNumber > 0 BEGIN

          DECLARE 
                 @RowStart INT
               , @RowEnd INT
               , @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
               , @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(500) 

          SELECT @SQL = N'
               SELECT 
                      c.CompanyID
                    , c.CompanyName
                    , p.PositionName
                    , p.PositionID
                    , p.UpdateTime
                    , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.UpdateTime DESC)  
               FROM dbo.Company c 
               JOIN dbo.Position p ON c.CompanyID = p.CompanyID 
               WHERE 1=1 '
               + CASE WHEN @KeyWord != '' THEN ' AND PositionName LIKE @KeyWord' ELSE '' END
               + CASE WHEN @WorkExperience != 0 THEN ' AND p.WorkExperience = @WorkExperience' ELSE '' END
               + CASE WHEN @CompanyType != 0 THEN ' AND c.CompanyType = @CompanyType' ELSE '' END
               + CASE WHEN @WorkType != 0 THEN ' AND p.WorkType = @WorkType' ELSE '' END

          SET @ParamDefinition = '@KeyWord NVARCHAR(50),
                                  @WorkExperience INT,
                                  @WorkType INT,
                                  @CompanyType INT,
                                  @PageSize INT,
                                  @PageNumber INT'

          SELECT 
                 @PageNumber = @PageNumber - 1
               , @RowStart = @PageSize * @PageNumber + 1
               , @RowEnd = @RowStart + @PageSize - 1
               , @SQL = '
          WITH AllJobs AS (' + @SQL + ')
          SELECT *
          FROM AllJobs a
          CROSS JOIN (
               SELECT TotalRows = Count(RowNumber)  
               FROM AllJobs
          ) t
          WHERE a.RowNumber BETWEEN ' + STR(@RowStart) + ' AND ' + STR(@RowEnd)

          EXEC sys.sp_executesql 
               @SQL, 
               @ParamDefinition,
               @KeyWord, 
               @WorkExperience,
               @WorkType, 
               @CompanyType, 
               @PageSize, 
               @PageNumber

     END

END
```

**Manual:**

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a nonclustered index on Position like so:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Position_WorkExperienceWorkTypePositionName 
ON Position (WorkExperience, WorkType, PositionName)
INCLUDE (PositionID, UpdateTime)
```

Comment: @StuartAinsworth-Thanks for your help.your index result in below:

(30 row(s) affected)
Table 'Company'. Scan count 0, logical reads 600226, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Position'. Scan count 2, logical reads 1802168, physical reads 0

Answer (score 0):

Also I would create another non-clustered index on Company like below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Company_CompanyId_Type
ON Company(CompanyId,CompanyType)
```

Because the where clause include "C.CompanyType=@CompanyType", without this index, this condition caused the table scan Company.
With this index, it's index seek.

Answer (score 0):

Company.CompanyID and Position.CompanyID should be indexed, and you might as well take advantage of CLUSTER indexing these two columns so that the rows get physically ordered in sync with their indexes. This should provide significant performance improvement.